# Incorrect screen boundaries on PS4

Tags: djmax-respect

I recently went back to play DJMax Respect on the PS4 via a different monitor than the TV I usually play on and found that the screen boundaries did not match up correctly with my monitor, showing a black bar around the normal image. This doesn't happen with any other games on the same system. I checked the settings menu as well as the collections menu, but was unable to find anywhere to adjust that specific setting.

Is there a way to manually adjust the screen boundaries to fit the size of my monitor?

Comment: This can sometimes be fixed by adjusting settings on the tv/monitor, rather than the system. Can you share some more information about the two screens you are using so we can tell if that's the case?

Comment: In a similar vein, it will be helpful to know whether parts of the image are cut off and "outside" the area shown by the screen, or if there are parts of the screen which are unused, with the image surrounded by blank areas.

Comment: I’ll see if I can get a screenshot when I get home and add it to the post. But in the mean time, I’m moving from a television to a computer monitor that I use for my PC as well. The image works fine for all other PS4 games and the OS. The only game producing this error is DJMax Respect, which makes a black bar surrounding the display of the game.

Comment: Essentially the game is producing an image roughly an inch smaller than the monitor itself and filling in the space with blackness.

Comment: I've edited that information into the post, feel free to change it if anything seems off. Thanks for the clarification!